# Simple Azure function fails : operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions, thread-safety

We have an Azure function whose only purpose is to put a message from Azure APIM to an Azure event hub.

The flow is : APIM -> Azure Function -> eventhub

The code in the Azure function is minimal :

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;


public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log, IAsyncCollector<string> outputEventHub2)
{
    string message = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
    await outputEventHub2.AddAsync(message);
    return new OkResult();
}
```

The APIM is triggered on a regular basis. From time to time, we see the following error appearing and the function stops working after that :

> Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive
> access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and
> corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.

As of that moment, all consecutive calls to the Azure function fail (404). Event a direct call to the function URL returns this response.

Restarting the Azure function remediates the problem for an impredictable amount of time.

Tried to reproduce it on a different environment, but so far without luck. The exact same piece of code has been running on a different environment without any issues for over 1 year.

Are there some known issues with thread-safeness in any of the libraries used ?

Would replacing this functionality by a simple Azure Logic App solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

> Would replacing this functionality by a simple Azure Logic App solve the issue ?

There was a similar error/issue with the combination of Azure Functions with Logic Apps as appeared in this [Microsoft Q&A Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/451778/functions-fail-with-34operations-that-change-non-c.html).

> The exact same piece of code has been running on a different environment without any issues for over 1 year.

This is the workaround did by [ChristianSchreuder-4912](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/christianschreuder-4912/) in his issue.

> Now by default the Logic App would automatically retry if an error is returned; however, when the 3 functions fail to load the Logic App gets a 404 error, which obviously doesn't trigger an automatic retry and the Logic App fails.
> It should also be noted that during the 5 minute run after any of the startups, all 6 functions work as intended because of the second warmup cycle.

This points to an issue within the Function App itself. ***I have tried to reproduce the error with a new Function App and Logic App which runs every 2 hours and has not had a single failure over the past 3 days. All functions always loaded correctly the first time.***

> I will redeploy these functions in a new Function App and see if the issue persists, but I doubt it will as this specific Function App appears to be broken.

I suggest recreating/resetting the environment and the same piece of function code built and trying to execute it might work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had seen the thread you refer to. However, in our case the function app keeps responding with 404 until it is restarted, a retry does not help. Only when the function app is restarted the error disappears for a while.